# How do I access server-status on MacOS X Lion?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I am running 10.7.4. I have Apache up and running. It serves html and php as expected. I was playing around with `apachectl` and wanted to see what `fullstatus` did. The complete command is:

```
 $ apachectl fullstatus
```

The response on the command line is:

```
Go to http://localhost:80/server-status in the web browser of your choice.
Note that mod_status must be enabled for this to work.
```

A `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep status` shows:

```
Syntax OK
 status_module (shared)
```

Upon doing that I get a 403 saying I don't have access to server-status. In looking at the access log I see:

```
localhost - - [29/May/2012:17:36:53 +0800] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 403 324
```

error log:

```
[Tue May 29 17:36:53 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/server-status
```

I pored over the `/etc/apache/httpd.conf` but couldn't find anything.

**How do I configure Apache so that I can view the server-status?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to handle requests to `/server-status` with mod_status, you will need the following lines somewhere in your configuration:

```
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
</Location>
```

Don't forget to restrict access to localhost or other trusted hosts using [Allow/Deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) or the newer [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) directives.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution if you are running Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan. *Note:* You need administrator privileges. (**sudo**)

- In your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` uncomment these lines

  - Line 153: `LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so`
  - Line 497: `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf`
- Now open `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf` and change lines 14-18 to

  - > `<Location /server-status>
    >   SetHandler server-status
    >   Require host localhost
    >   </Location>`

Now you can open the URL `http://localhost/server-status` with your web browser and see the apache status.

For a "fullstatus" place the text `ExtendedStatus On` within `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf` right before the `<Location /server-status>` line.